# how to use linq to sql with if using

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

this is my with if code, but all condition been and keyword, how can i use with or

```
if (cbAlis.Checked)
            _search.Where(x => x.faturaturu.ToString().Equals(1));
        if (cbSatis.Checked)
            _search.Where(x => x.faturaturu.ToString().Equals(2));
        if (cbAcik.Checked)
            _search.Where(x => x.faturatipi.Equals("Açık"));
        if (cbKapali.Checked)
            _search.Where(x => x.faturatipi.Equals("Kapalı"));
        if (cbIade.Checked)
            _search.Where(x => x.faturatipi.Equals("İade"));
        if (cbZayiIade.Checked)
            _search.Where(x => x.faturatipi.Equals("Zayi İade"));
        if (cbMuhtelif.Checked)
            _search.Where(x => x.faturatipi.Equals("Muhtelif"));
        if (cbIptal.Checked)
            _search.Where(x => x.faturatipi.Equals("İptal"));
```

i,m sorry for my english. i hope could told.

Comment: You just need `_search = _search.Where(...);`

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: Add all those checkboxes to an `IEnumerable` or `IDictionary` with the key strings. Writing `if` for each one is going to be tedious. If you're repeating something over and over again, that's a sure sign it needs to be refactored.

Comment: Which fields do you want to add with OR keyword?

Comment: `.ToString().Equals(1)` will always be `false` since an `int` is not a `string`.

Comment: i want to using all fields or keyword.

_search=_search.where(..)
i when using the same field set different value no enumaration yielded error has been

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var urufilters = new List<int>();

if (cbAlis.Checked)
   filters.Add("1");
if (cbSatis.Checked)
   filters.Add("2");

if (filters.Any())
{
   _search = _search.Where(x => filters.Contains(faturaturu));
}
```

And repeat for your string values.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you have a section where you are searching by the text of the checkbox, this is one of the simpler that I came up with:

First put the checkboxes in a panel, or something similar so that they are in a group. Then the code would become simple like this:

```
var itm = panel
  .OfType<CheckBox>()
  .Where(x => x.Checked)
  .Select(x => _search.Where(y => y.faturatipi.Equals(x.Text)));
```

Please note that with this method, the first two still need an if.

Answer (score 0):

You can define dictionary with filters for each checkbox:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Dictionary<CheckBox, Func<Model, bool>> _checkboxFilters;
        private IEnumerable<Model> _search;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _search = new List<Model>
            {
                new Model {Property1 = 1, Property2 = "aaa"},
                new Model {Property1 = 2, Property2 = "bbb"},
                new Model {Property1 = 3, Property2 = "Açık"},
                new Model {Property1 = 4, Property2 = "Açık"},
            };

            _checkboxFilters = new Dictionary<CheckBox, Func<Model, bool>>
            {
                {checkBox1, new Func<Model,bool>(x => x.Property1.Equals(1))},
                {checkBox2, new Func<Model,bool>(x => x.Property2.Equals("Açık"))}
            };
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var checkBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList();
            var checkedCheckBoxes = checkBoxes.Where(n => n.Checked);

            foreach (var checkBox in checkedCheckBoxes)
            {
                if (_checkboxFilters.ContainsKey(checkBox))
                {
                    var filter = _checkboxFilters[checkBox];
                    _search = _search.Where(filter);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Model
    {
        public int Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
```